# How to send csv file through intent

Tags: android, android-intent

This is the function to start share intent
While Shairing the share box is opening and I can select all options like whatsapp ,gmail while selecting those option the file is not getting attached

```
private void OpenShare(String filename) {


        Uri uri = Uri.parse(( getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getPath()+filename));


        Intent sharingIntent = new Intent();
        sharingIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/*");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "share file with"));



    }
```

Share box is opening , please help me to solve this

eror message

```
2020-02-28 20:09:19.821 14722-14903/com.digicita.digiflow E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for cn.teddymobile.free.anteater.den.provider
2020-02-28 20:09:20.719 14722-14821/com.digicita.digiflow E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2020-02-28 20:09:21.484 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2020-02-28 20:09:24.422 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: >>> msg's executing time is too long
2020-02-28 20:09:24.422 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Blocked msg = { when=-2s378ms what=100 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=ActivityRecord{40b44d2 token=android.os.BinderProxy@67a38f1 {com.digicita.digiflow/com.digicita.digiflow.MainActivity}} } , cost  = 2328 ms
2020-02-28 20:09:24.422 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: >>>Current msg List is:
2020-02-28 20:09:24.422 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <1>  = { when=-2s350ms what=101 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=com.android.internal.os.SomeArgs@43079a3 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.423 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <2>  = { when=-2s325ms what=109 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H arg1=1 obj=android.os.BinderProxy@929e1d }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.423 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <3>  = { when=-1s845ms what=103 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H obj=com.android.internal.os.SomeArgs@4c5a4a0 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.423 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <4>  = { when=-1s845ms what=137 target=android.app.ActivityThread$H arg1=1 obj=android.os.BinderProxy@67a38f1 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.423 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <5>  = { when=-1s468ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.424 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <6>  = { when=-1s402ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.424 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <7>  = { when=-1s162ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.424 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <8>  = { when=-1s100ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.424 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <9>  = { when=-1s92ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.425 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: Current msg <10>  = { when=-1s84ms what=0 target=android.os.Handler callback=androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat$FontCallback$2 }
2020-02-28 20:09:24.425 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/ANR_LOG: >>>CURRENT MSG DUMP OVER<<<
2020-02-28 20:09:38.731 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2020-02-28 20:09:47.514 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2020-02-28 20:10:19.139 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2020-02-28 20:14:01.323 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
2020-02-28 20:14:24.794 14722-14722/com.digicita.digiflow E/Parcel: Reading a NULL string not supported here.
```

Comment: where you want to share? means throw email?

Comment: whatsapp ,email

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the intent-filter in the manifest.

```
 <data android:mimeType="text/comma_separated_values/csv" />
```

And Change the MIME type to `text/plain` , `text/csv` or `text/comma-separated-values`.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
intent.setType("text/*");
```

make sure you have enough apps installed on your test device.
`("text/csv")` is the correct format but you can try using `("text/plain")` which will open all the text editors installed as well.